# Как обработать клик по ячейке tableView

Tags: swift

[image: схема приложения]

Здравствуйте все! Я хочу обработать клик по ячейке с помощью 
`override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`
Сложность в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как мне обратиться к данным на другом контроллере. То есть я хочу при клике по ячейке tableView взять данные из поля Name(UILabel) и перенести в другой контроллер в поле uchLabel(UILabel).
Как можно осуществить сие действие?

Comment: Как передать данные я понял (performSegueWithIdentifier). А вот как их принять потом?

Comment: Недавно задавал похожий вопрос, посмотрите, может поможет: http://bit.ly/2aTTeaT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае если вы уже создали `segue` в сториборде (Не будет дважды открыть detail controller)

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Detail" {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UchastokViewController
        destVC.yourPropepry = String(sender)
    }
}
```

В случае же, если вы еще не создавали в сториборде `segue` (Show Detail)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ToDetail", sender: loans[indexPath.row].title)
}
```

Это позволит вам "ходить" без явного указания `segue` в сториборде

Answer (score 0):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ToDetail" {
        let DestinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UchastokViewController
        DestinationVC.uchTitle = String(sender)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("ToDetail", sender: loans[indexPath.row].title)
}
```

Comment: Однако теперь у меня viewController открывается 2 раза. Кто нибудь может подсказать почему так?